# Using Visio 2013 to create a timeline and can't get rid of dotted lines in the timeline

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm using Visio 2013 to create a cylindrical timeline for a project.  I have many overlapping activities in the timeline and Visio automatically fills the cylindrical timeline with dotted lines underneath my call out items.  How do I get rid of them?

Comment: What's the dotted lines? It is better to provide a screenshot about the drawing for better understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, we can add a Expanded timeline to an existing timeline as a second timeline to show more detail. The expanded timeline represents a segment of the original timeline, but you work with it individually.

The expanded timeline uses **dashed lines** to indicate the section of the original timeline that it represents. Therefore, the dotted line you mentioned is the relationship between expended timeline and the original timeline. We cannot to remove it.
[image]

If you don't like the dotted line in Visio drawing, using other Cylindrical timeline instead of Expended timeline shape as a workaround.

Comment: The question is not about expanded timelines, and the author is already using a cylindrical timeline.